# Java SortedCollection interface?

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for an interface describing the contract *order of elements is important but nothing else*.

I could use `List` but `SortedSet` does not implement `List`. I could use `Iterable` but `HashSet` does implement `Iterable` while not being sorted.

What would you recommend?

Comment: There is no such interface. The common interfaces of `ArrayList` and `TreeSet` are `Collection` and `Iterable`, but these interfaces do are also implemented by `HashSet`. How would you use such an interface?

Comment: What do you mean "order of elements is important"?

Comment: Well, the idea behind a `List` is fast access to both ends and fast traversal. Sorting is a slow operation in lists. Meanwhile a `Set` is a bag with no particular optimizations towards any area. If you need it to be always sorted, then `TreeSet` is the class for you, and you'll just have to use it's iterator. Alternatively you can sort any modifiable list using `java.util.Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I would use such an interface to describe a contract. I need an order of elements and originally did not want to require a comparator, but it seams like there is no other option.

Comment: Actually `List` preserves order of elements inserted, it also could be easily sorted with `Collections.sort(...)` method as @coladict mentioned. If you need a set that just preserves the order of inserted items, you can use `LinkedHashSet`. It implements `Iterable` and preserves the order of insertion. But it's a particular implementation, not an interface.